# Why does nothing prints out after window.location.href?

Tags: javascript

As am I learning and experimenting more and more with javascript (I'm a newbie), I'm coming up with a lot of questions. I looked this question up online but it wasn't the exact same scenario.
This is fairly straightforward. Why do my hello2 and hello3 not print in the console? (I've also tried it without the setTimeout, with the setTimeout I'm able to see hello(otherwise it switches pages super fast). Thank you so much for any help!

```
function introPage() {
  console.log("hello");
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/youPage.html';
    console.log("hello2");
  }, 7000);
  console.log("hello3");
}
introPage();
```

Answer (score 2):

I get `hello` and `hello3` back and then 7 seconds later the page tries to load which resets my console. I'm sure `hello2` is sent to console at the same time, so it just never shows up in the console, that we can see.

```
introPage()
hello
hello3
```

```js
function introPage() {
  console.log("hello");
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/youPage.html';
    console.log("hello2");
  }, 7000);
  console.log("hello3");
}
introPage();
```

Edit: Actually, if you run this code snippet you can catch it print out the `hello3` before it reloads.

Comment: Thank you! So in my mind, hello2 should print in the console after the page is reloaded but it never does. So if I wanted to see hello2 would I need a setTimeout inside a setTimeout? But also it still doesn't make sense how the reloading of the page and the hello2 console log just happen to be at the exact same time which would be why it doesn't appear in the console?

Comment: Because it is running at the same time as the page transfer, it is being output to the console session that invoked it. When the page refreshes that console session is cleared and a new session is created. You can test this by trying to run `introPage();` again, it won't be defined.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the output as **hello**  and then **hello3**

This is due to the call-back function. The callback function executes after the execution of every line in a function.

So if you would remove this line below from your code.

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/youPage.html';
```

Your output would be

hello

hello3

and then hello2 after every seven seconds.

You are not getting output hello2 because of the redirection code running first. As a result page refresh and console got clear.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thank you! To make my question as clear as possible I got rid of my "initial" code so instead of console.log("hello2"); I had a function call which inside had a console log. But when my page reload I never got a hello2 after the 7 seconds.

Comment: your function should lie on the second page which you have redirected.
In other words, your function should be allocated on the script of second page.